# VIM netrw creates directory but returns **error** (netrw) unable to make directory

Tags: vim, vi

I'm attempting to create a directory from within a netrc explorer window, however, upon creating the directory netrw returns **error** (netrw) unable to make directory.  The directory is actually created in the background, but my cursor is brought to the error message and netrw does not update the directory listing.

Comment: Netrw's "d" command for making directories depends on the variable:

    g:netrw_localmkdir

What is the value of that variable? You need to have netrw invoked first:

    vim .   , 
    :echo g:netrw_localmkdir

Does that variable hold a proper command? What happens when you try it from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, my problem was that I had set the wrong shell in my vimrc, changing that fixed it for me.

To find the shell you're using do this in your terminal:

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

Then I change my .vimrc to use the correct shell:

```
set shell=/bin/zsh
```

Then to verify Vim is using the right shell you can do:

```
echo &shell
/bin/zsh
```